# umount stalled and unable to kill its process

Tags: ubuntu, mount, kill

Sometimes when I remove SD card I can notice that when I reinsert it - it doesn't mount by itself.
Also I've notice that umount process is stalled and I cannot kill it (not even with -9).
I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first: get out from that directory :) Joking.. but not so much,  thinking how many times I run `umount` and it gives me back an error because I'm *indeed* inside the mounted folder.

Try running `lsof | grep <your_sd_card_directory_here>`, to check if that directory is in use.

Example output of `lsof | grep /mnt/share`, `/mnt/share` is mounted:

```
COMMAND     PID  TID    USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
lsof      11930         root  cwd       DIR              253,2        15     213678 /mnt/share
```

This is showing that `lsof` is being run exactly from `/mnt/share` with FD (File Descriptor) **cwd**, the **C**urrent **W**orking **D**irectory.

If you see the same.. get out from that directory ;)

Comment: Can this be related to copying a file onto that SD card and removing the card without sync'ing?

Comment: What you mean by sync'ing? Is the sd configured to be synced in some program? If the sd mount directory and related files/services are free, you should be able to unmount and mount it again. Try `findmnt`, it should tell you where exactly is the sd mounted, and then use `lsof | grep sdmountpoint` to find out what actually is using it.

Comment: I meant that I used "cp" instruction earlier and later "sync" in the terminal.  Unfortunately I resolved the issue with hard reset but I'm sure it will come back and then I'll post the output of findmnt, lsof and iostat.

Answer (score 3):

umount process is stuck in system call and kernel waiting for something - perhaps it's a bad driver issue, because normally USB drivers correctly handle such situations and let userspace processes go on to exit, instead of hanging them into kernel mode, when user suddenly pulls out USB stick or SD card from reader.